# Using GUID Primary Keys & Auto-Increment Primary Keys on different tables in the same DB

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, primary-key, relational-database

So I'm designing a database using MS SQL with an invoices table and a clients table.  My clients table looks something like:

```
--------------------------------
Client ID   |   Name   |   Phone   |   Address  |  City  |  State  |  Zip  
________________________________
```

Where the client ID is a GUID primary key.

My invoices table looks something like:

```
--------------------------------
Invoice ID   |   Client ID   |   Date/Time   |   Price    
________________________________
```

Where the invoice ID would be a number (starting at say, 1000) and auto-incrementing by 1.

Is this ok, or bad practice?  I just don't want my invoices to be printing out with invoice # `336868de-7778-41fc-ae7f-662f76d5615a....`

Comment: What is the motivation for using the GUID in the customers table? GUIDs are wider than integers and can cause fragmentation issues as well depending on how they are generated. For that reason I wouldn't use a `GUID` in preference to an `int` as PK for the invoices table just for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally don't see a reason to ever use a GUID - if I need something auto-generated, identity it is. So to answer your question, that's perfectly fine. And as Martin commented, I'd consider using an auto-number for your customer ids as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I don't think there's anything necessarily wrong with having different data types for different ID numbers.

I *do* think you might want to reconsider an autoincrement number for invoices, though. I don't think any platform guarantees that autoincrement id numbers will be without gaps.

The only thing accountants hate worse than gaps are gaps without backing documentation, and that's what you're about to have. (Of course, a gap that has backing documentation isn't really a gap, because you can account for all the numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

GUID primary keys make sense if there is a reasonable chance you'll be porting the table to a different database. If you feel this is true for Client but not for Invoice, then I don't see the two different key types as a problem. However, looking at your particular example, Invoice and Client may be ported together since there is a dependency. In that case, you should probably have the same primary key type for both tables.

Comment: Porting to a different database shouldn't really be a big deal - you're going to have to change NEWID() and other related syntax just as much as you're going to have to change IDENTITY-based syntax. Now, distributing your system across multiple databases or servers might be a valid reason, but you can still use identity ranges for that.

Comment: Actually: if you consider porting to a different database, I would **avoid** GUID's at all costs, since not all other databases readily support it....